# Configuration required for ant xml to build correct jar using java 1.8.0_40 and ant 1.9.0

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, exe

I am trying to build jar for my project using jdk 1.8.0_40 and ant version 1.9.0, jar is getting build but while converting this jar to .exe, it is not able to find main class as I have correctly mentioned my main class.I am using eclipse Mar Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Earlier I was using jdk 1.7.0_79 version and ant 1.8.4  and everything was working fine.

I am facing issue while upgrading from jdk 1.7.0_79 to jdk 1.8.0_40.

Below is my ant xml which are using to build my jar.Let me know if any configuration is required for java 1.8 to build proper jar.

```
<property name="jar.name" value="SAFAL.jar" />
<property name="source.root" value="src" />
<property name="class.root" value="bin" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
<property name="jar.dir" value="C:\D\SAFAL-Exe" />
<property name="Main-Class" value="com.sungard.ktt.main.SAFALEval" />
<property name="conf.pkj" value="com/sungard/ktt/business/configurations" />
<property name="img.pkj" value="com/sungard/ktt/business/images" />

<path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${class.root}" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean" description="cleans up build structures">
    <delete dir="${class.root}" />
    <delete file="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" description="sets up build structures">
    <mkdir dir="${class.root}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compiles all java classes">
    <javac srcdir="${source.root}" destdir="${class.root}" debug="on" optimize="off" deprecation="on" source="1.8" target="1.8" includeantruntime = "false">

        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
    </javac>

    <mkdir dir="${class.root}/${conf.pkj}" />
    <mkdir dir="${class.root}/${img.pkj}" />

    <copy todir="${class.root}/${conf.pkj}">
        <fileset dir="${source.root}/${conf.pkj}" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${class.root}/${img.pkj}">
        <fileset dir="${source.root}/${img.pkj}" />
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile"> 

    <delete file="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}" quiet="true" failonerror="false" />

    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}">

        <fileset dir="${class.root}" includes="**/*.*" />
        <fileset dir="${source.root}" includes="**/api/*.java,**/api/vo/*.java"/>

        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" />


        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${Main-Class}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
        </manifest>

    </jar>


</target>


<target name="run">
    <java fork="true" classname="${Main-Class}">
        <classpath>
            <path location="./${jar.name}" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `java` task you are using `./${jar.name}` as the location of your jar - this is relying on the current directory being set correctly. All the rest of your code uses `${jar.dir}/${jar.name}` as the path for the jar, so change the `java` task to do the same:

```
<target name="run">
    <java fork="true" classname="${Main-Class}">
        <classpath>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```